# The type or namespace 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference ?)

Tags: c#, .net, reference, log4net

Find the steps i followed ,

1. I installed the log4net from Nuget manager.(LOG4NET version 2.0.15)
2. Added the log4net.config file and defined the configurations(Parameter, layout, appender etc)
3. Am using ADOAppender to log the 'INFO' into the database.
4. After installing and adding the .config file , in order to configure i added the below piece of code in `assemblyinfo.cs`.
   `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]`

but it's throwing the above mentioned error

> 'The type or namespace 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference ?)'

5. I tried clean, rebuild and  restarting VS the error still persists
6. I even tried to change the .NET framework version (Current version 4.5.1), the error is still there.
7. I checked under references and log4net references is added.
8. Tried re-installing the log4net package too.

Please suggest why the error is still there

Comment: For log4net.config file is set Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always. This is important because we need the log4net.config file to be copied to the bin folder when you build and run your app

Comment: @BhushanMuttha i have made that change(log4net.config file is set Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always) , still am getting the same error

Comment: @Ramaya , Did you try rebuilding after that and check bin/output folder , Is log4net config file present or not ?

Comment: @BhushanMuttha Yes , i rebuilded the solution and am able to find Log4Net.config file, log4net.dll and lo4net XML document in my bin folder. But when i tried opening the Log4net.config from bin folder am getting the below error 

An error occurred in 'Miscellaneous Files' while attempting to open 'Log4Net.config'
Could not find file 'C:\Incentivecomp\DEV_FY22_PM_LSS_Ph2\QI_Admin\bin\Log4Net.config'.